# Python last line of for loop executed twice

Tags: python, for-loop

Why is "no" printed an additional time? How can the problem be fixed without writing the loop in a separate function?

```
for i  in range(2):
    if i == 1:
        print("yes")
    print("no")
```

Result:

```
no
yes
no
```

Comment: Put `continue` as an additional line in the `if` block or put `print("no")` in an `else:` block.

Answer (score 3):

Let see what happened:

when `i=0`, it print `no`
when `i=`, it firstly print `yes`, after that printing `no`.

EDIT: to fix it, you can

```
for i  in range(2):
    if i == 1:
       print("yes")
    else:
       print("no")
```

Or,

```
for i  in range(2):
    if i == 1:
        print("yes")
        continue
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 1):

The other `print` statement happens *unconditionally*; that is, there's no `else` to prevent it from firing again.

You can prevent it by using `else`:

```
for i  in range(2):
    if i == 1:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

Answer (score 1):

u can also use keyword `break` to fix it,like below:

```
for i in range(2):
    if i==1:
        print('yes')
        break
    print('no')
```

when i==1 break out the for func,maybe this is better understanded